# how to bind table from database to checkedListBox?

Tags: c#

i have this table MEN: id,Fname and i have checkeddListBox

i bind like this:

this.ListAtar.DataSource = dsView.Tables[0];

this.ListAtar.DisplayMember = dsView.Tables[0].Columns[0].ColumnName; //Fname

this.ListAtar.ValueMember = dsView.Tables[0].Columns[1].ColumnName;   //ID

but if i pick some items, how i can see the list of the ID that i pick ?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to set the [CheckedListBox.DisplayMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.displaymember.aspx) to `Fname` and the [CheckedListBox.ValueMember](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.valuemember.aspx) to `id`.

```
myCheckedListBox.DisplayMember = "Fname";
myCheckedListBox.ValueMember = "id";
```

For what it's worth, it's easier to set these values in the Designer.

Comment: @Gold:  There's example code if you drill down in the links provided.

Answer (score 0):

you bind the datasource then set the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties then call the DataBind method

like a when you play around with dropdownlist, combox, listbox, etc...